# Create table with rows using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create tables **containing rows** once, when the database is created. Is there a 'native' way how to do this rather than having to use the session and check if the rows exist before adding them?

This is sample code I'm using..

/database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from ..const import (
    DATABASE_URL
)

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

/dataset/menu/model.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, exc

from ...database import Base, SessionLocal


class Menu(Base):
    __tablename__ = "menus"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String)
    icon = Column(String)
```

/main.py

```
from .database import database

database.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=database.engine)
```

Comment: When you use `flask-sqlalchemy` and `alchemical` , after you initialize the database, and import it in flask shell. if you do `db.create_all()` it will create the tables if they do not exist and if the tables do exist they will remain unmodified. I am not sure of that is the same thing if you do with raw `sqlalchemy` though

Comment: @collinsmarra looks like it's pretty much similar, but I would also like to add not just tables when the db is created, but also some rows in certain tables. Is that possible?

Comment: Then I would suggest using [alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/) to do database upgrades. If you are using `flask`, the extension [flask-migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will do a lot of these stuff for you